# Issue inserting data into my Postgres DB, Error: missing data for column "xyz" , when there is actually a zero as a value

Tags: python, postgresql

I keep getting this error when trying to transfer data from an API into my PostgreSQL dB.

This is my code below: The error occurs due to zeroes in every row for a column from an API. (look at the image added at the end of this post to understand. Below is the code I use to pull and copy data into my dB.

```
def copy_from_stringio(conn, df, table):
    """
    Here we are going save the dataframe in memory 
    and use copy_from() to copy it to the table
    """
    # save dataframe to an in memory buffer
    buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(buffer, index_label='id', header=False)
    buffer.seek(0)
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(buffer, table, sep=",", null='')
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    print("copy_from_stringio() done")
    cursor.close()

def move_column_inplace(df, col, pos):
    col = df.pop(col)
    df.insert(pos, col.name, col)

previousday = {}
for x in tickers:
        r = requests.get(f"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{x}/previous?token={IEX_SANDBOX_TOKEN}")
        try:
            data = r.json()
        except ValueError:
            print("Response content is not valid JSON")
            
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
        move_column_inplace(df, 'symbol', 0)

        previousday[x] = df


# for x in tickers:
#     copy_from_stringio(conn, previousday[x], 'security_price')
```

Here is a picture of the error and as you can see in the column `change_over_time`, you can see a 0 in the cell. Every row from this one API pull has a zero for that column. That zero is interfering with the pull. I added a `nullable = True` when creating the models to hope fix the error, that did not work. I'd like to keep that column there if possible, makes it much easier to pull data when the tables are the same shape. Anyone know a way to fix this or a better alternative solution?

[note the `change_over_time column with a zero]

[image: Look at the table]

This is my table definition:

```
class SecurityPrice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'security_price'
    idx = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True)
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('date', Date, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    open = Column('open', Numeric)
    high = Column('high', Numeric)
    low = Column('low', Numeric)
    close = Column('close', Numeric)
    volume = Column('volume', BigInteger)
    adj_open = Column('adj_open', Numeric)
    adj_high = Column('adj_high', Numeric)
    adj_low = Column('adj_low', Numeric)
    adj_close = Column('adj_close', Numeric)
    adj_volume = Column('adj_volume', BigInteger)
    change = Column('change', Numeric)
    changepercent = Column('change_percent', Numeric)
    label = Column('label', String )
    changeovertime = Column('change_over_time', Numeric, nullable=True)
    #security_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('security.id',
    #                                 onupdate="CASCADE",
    #                                 ondelete="CASCADE"),
    #                                 nullable=False)
    # UniqueConstraint('date', 'security_id')
    security = relationship('security')
```

Comment: Can you put a sample row in the question? The image abbreviates it with `...` just at the key part...

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps specify the column names in the `COPY` command, and let it use defaults for the rest?

Comment: @sabik hey , is the datatable row above not enough? the error text you're seeing is from my function that turns the JSON into an CSV, then copies it into postgres.

Comment: @IronMan , would that even matter for my case?

Comment: Right; I'm still suspicious that there's not enough commas in the CSV. I guess the datatable row helps, although perhaps printing out the contents of `buffer` could show something odd. In addition, what's the table definition? Do the columns match exactly? (Specifying the column names in the `COPY` command could avoid that, eg. if there's an automatic row-id column...)

Comment: Hey @sabik , I have updated the OG post with the table definition. Tables do match exactly.

Comment: I see two problems here; (a) there's an extra column, "label"; and (b) some of the columns are in a different order, so the data may be imported incorrectly. Both of these would be either resolved or at least detected with a better error message by specifying the column names in the `COPY` command...

Comment: @sabik The problem originated from the "label" column that I was not aware of. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the issue is the API that i'm using to pull and store data with. The developers added a column that I was not aware about to one of their tables, which ruined the accuracy of the CSV delimiter, hence the reason why there is missing data!

Moral of the story, make sure you are up to date with the libraries that you use for important stuff!